# Are Portlets widely used or they are very rare?

Tags: java, servlets, portlet

I heard a lot about servlets/JSP. But almost nothing about portlets. Is this technology popular and really used in production commercially?

Comment: This will attract more opinions than answers but no, portlets are not used as much any more.  Portals in general are not as popular as they once were and so the use of portlets is not as popular.  That's not to say portal software doesn't exist but it is a pretty specialized server.

Comment: I agree with the opinion-attraction (and indeed have a different opinion) - it depends where you look. Granted, small applications are quickly written with any other technology than portlets. But portals have evolved and provide a lot of integration into enterprise infrastructure. Granted, they're not "hot technology" as they used to be, but a solid basis to build on. And "portals" provide a lot more than just "portlets" these days. Disclaimer: Look at my profile ;) (and yes, I'm also voting to close this question)